# brew install php70-mongodb not working

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, homebrew

I installed php-mongodb with brew, but when I tried to connect it says no plugin.

```
echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
```

**output : not loaded**

The steps I followed: [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php)

```
$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
$ brew install php70-mongodb

$ sudo brew services restart httpd
```

my php versiyon :

```
$ php -v
```

output :

```
PHP 7.0.27 (cli) (built: Feb 15 2018 16:59:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Did you configure the extension in `php.ini`?

Comment: Apache does not work when I add extension = mongodb.so to php.ini file

Comment: Triple check the extension definition. Are you providing the correct path? Is your string quoted?

Comment: this not easy. How many times have I checked, but there is no problem with the extension and file location. and does not allow it to function in any way.

Comment: And you restarted Apache after this change?

Comment: No, it will not restart. because it says that the module is not loaded even though it is loading. extension=mongodb.so when I remove the php.ini file restarting

Comment: Please post the errors you see trying to restart Apache

Comment: apache did not give an error. I removed the whole system and reinstalled it and made the steps make again. I could only solve the problem this way. I probably missed a place and I still did not notice it. It looks like no problem. thank you for helping. @sorak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They removed the tap homebrew/homebrew-php so you need to install it trouguh pecl, first make sure you have pecl installed and working properly.

After that run:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Check if the extension is enabled with:

```
php -i | grep mongo
```

You should get an output like:

```
mongodb
libmongoc bun
dled version => 1.9.4
libmongoc SSL => enabled
...
```

If you don't get that output, you should check your php.ini and add this line to your php.ini

```
extension="mongodb.so"
```

Comment: Homebrew-php had this problem before it was removed. and did not solve the `pecl` setup. However, there is no problem with php56 and php72 versions. That's why I got it working at php72. Thank you again for your interest.

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

Try to install using MacPorts. it's better than homebrew

it worked fine to me with no problem in my php 7.1:

```
sudo port install php71-mongodb
```

if you have other version than 7.1. check this page:

https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=mongodb

Comment: I had to add the extension on php ini myself : $  sudo find / -name mongodb.so -> find just installed instalation then add it full path on php ini like : extension="fullpath_mongodb.so"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using php72 with php72-mongodb on macos. I've installed like following:

```
brew install php72 php72-mongodb
```

And then everything is OK when I've restarted my httpd/apache or nginx server.

You can check your setup with:

```
php -i | grep mongodb
```

You'll see something likes that following in my opinion:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-mongodb.ini,
mongodb
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Comment: I need a version that works with php70, not php72. it's different, php72 version this bug fixed but php70 not working. problem is php70.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can check what's happening when you run `brew install php70 or php72` at the brew's source code.